# When a guildCreate event is triggered in discord.js, is there a way to tell whether it's from joining a server, or a server becoming available?

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I've come across an error where when I use `client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)`, it shows `available` as `false`. After a bit of googling, I found [this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#guild-availability) which says that a guildCreate event will be triggered when the guild becomes available again. The thing is, according to [this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#guild-create), the guildCreate event will trigger when the bot joins a guild, AND when the guild becomes available, but I need the bot to do something different for each. I have no clue where to start, so I have no code to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking, apparently, the discord developer doc's guildCreate is different from the one that I would recieve.

Answer (score 0):

guildCreate:
Emitted whenever the client joins a guild.

To check if the guild is available you can just simply add check to your code for example

```
if(guild.available){
    //do stuff
}
```

This is just simple example how you can check guild's availability